# How to see the triangulation of an object

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am reading simplicial complex in Algebraic topology by Spanier. I read the definition of triangulation of a space and polyhedral. I cant get a picture about what we mean by triangulating a space and why we are triangulating a space.
I like to do things with intuition. so give me some suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polygon is a triangulation of the circle $S^1$.  A polyhedron such as icosahedron, octahedron, or tetrahedron ($\partial \Delta^3$) is a triangulation of the sphere $S^2$.  There is a triangulation of the torus $S^1 \times S^1$ using $14$ triangles, and I believe that is the minimum possible.

By building a triangulated model of a space, one can study it as a combinatorial object.  Many invariants, such as Euler characteristic, become exercises in counting subsimplices.

There are some rather [deep results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_%28topology%29#Piecewise_linear_structures) in the study of whether a manifold admits a *piecewise-linear* triangulation in dimension $n \ge 5$.  This is a bit surprising at the outset, as every manifold of dimension at most $4$ admits a PL structure, another example of the misleading impression that small examples can give and justification of mathematical rigor.

(Just for fun, [here](http://zoltanb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/triangulate.png)'s a triangulation of model of a horse, presumably homeomorphic to $S^2$.)

Comment: is there any book with lots of examples?